# Max out of a range of List values

Tags: c#, list, max

I am trying to find the Max value out of the last five HSwDMI List values, but I am not sure if my for() loop is the right way of doing it. 
I would have thought that I could use a function to give me the highest value in the last five, but I couldn't find anything.

Also, the code below throws the error "Use of unassigned local variable newHSwDMI" and I can't quite get why. 
It works when I declare newHSwDMI at class level, though.

Any advice will be appreciated.

```
private List<double> HSwDMI;
HSwDMI = new List<double>();
....
if ((!HSwDMIbool && DMI1[2] - DMI1[1] > 0.001 && DMI1[2] - DMI1[3] > 0.001)
    || (!HSwDMIbool && FlatIndBar && FlatDMI[a-1] - DMI1[1] > 0.001 && FlatDMI[a-1] - DMI(Closes[2], 
    Convert.ToInt32(DmiPeriod)).Values[0].GetValueAt(flatDMIbar - 1) > 0.001))
{
    var hSwDMI = DMI1[2];
    HSwDMI.Add(hSwDMI);
    HSwDMIbar = CurrentBar - 2;
    var hSwDMIprice = Highs[2].GetValueAt(HSwDMIbar);
    HSwDMIprice.Add(hSwDMIprice);
    HSwDMIbool = true;
    b++;
}
if (HSwDMIbool)   
{
    double newHSwDMI;
    for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if (HSwDMI[i] > HSwDMI[i-1])
            newHSwDMI = HSwDMI[i];
    }
    LastHSwDMI.Add(newHSwDMI);
}
```

Comment: `newHSwDMI` is declared within the `if (HSwDMIbool)` but is referred to outside that and so is out of scope.

Comment: There is no place where you access the last 5 elements. (From List.Count-5 to List.Count-1). You check the first 6 Elements, from 0 to 5. And you don't find a Max, you find the last Element, that is larger than it's predecessor.

Comment: if the `if (HSwDMI[i] > HSwDMI[i-1])` in the loop is never `true`, then `newHSwDMI` will never be assigned a value. You usually solve this by assigning the first value before the loop and then start looping at the second value. `double newHSwDMI = HSwDMI[0]; for ( int i = 1; ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using linq you could do something like this

```
var listCount = HSwDMI.Count; 
var maxValueInHswDMI = HSwDMI.Skip(listCount-5).Max();

// HSWDMI.Skip(x) skips x amount of items in the list and max returns the max value among the remaining items..
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to get the HSwDMI list index of that Max value as well?

Comment: var index = HSDMI.IndexOf(HSwDMI.Skip(listCount-5).Max());

with something like this